# error in running code machine/deep learning

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not able to solve this error:

```
NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
1 modelFns = { 'vgg_segnet':Models.VGGSegnet.VGGSegnet}    
NameError: name 'Models' is not defined
```

My code:

```
import VGGSegnet
import LoadBatches
from keras.models import load_model

modelFns = { 'vgg_segnet':Models.VGGSegnet.VGGSegnet}
modelFN = modelFns[ model_name ]
m = modelFN( n_classes , input_height=input_height, input_width=input_width   )
```

Comment: did you import or define `Models` anywhere? Because that is needed for your code to work

Comment: Also, there are a bunch more undefined names in the next two lines... is this your whole code?

Comment: I solved the error after i WROTE VGGsegnet.VGGsegnet instead of Models.VGGsegnet.VGGsegnet